# Specific double summation problems

Tags: summation

How should I evaluate double sum of a number?

Example
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n 4 $$

And how should I evaluate double sum of $$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n i^2 $$

Note:- I am completely new at these. I am good at single summations though. So if possible explain each and every of the step(I learn quickly). And if possible also provide some reference to further polish my skills.

Comment: 1) By finding the explicit formula for $g(i):=\sum_{k=i+1}^n 4$ and then summing $\sum_{i=0}^n g(i)$. 2) By finding the explicit formula for $h(i):=\sum_{k=i+1}^n i^2$ and then summing $\sum_{i=0}^n h(i)$. Fairly easy both $h$ and $g$, but after you may want to know the formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^m$ when $m=1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n 4 =4 \sum_{i=0}^n (n-i)=4n(n+1)-4\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2n(n+1)$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^ni^2=\sum_{i=0}^ni^2(n-i)=n\sum_{i=0}^ni^2-\sum_{i=0}^ni^3$$
$$=n\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)-\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}n^2(n+1)(2n+1)-\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2$$
$$=n^2(n+1)\left[\frac{1}{6}(2n+1)-\frac{1}{4}(n+1)\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}n^2(n^2-1)$$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html

Comment: I understood everything except the second equality in which you somehow converted the $$\sum_{k=i+1}^n 1  =n-i $$

Comment: There are $(n-i)$ terms of $1$ summed together.

Comment: How did you get (n-i)

Comment: Just count from $i+1$ to $n$. How many terms?

Comment: oh got it thank you. Btw if it was k=i then the term should be (n-i-1) right?

Comment: Should be $n-i+1$. You got one more term didn't you?

Comment: When k = i+1 the resultant term is (n-i). Subtract 1 from both sides. Shouldn't for k =i it should be n-i-1

Comment: In general $\sum_p^q$ has $q-p+1$ terms.

Comment: Oh okay then, thank you

Comment: For example, counting from $10$ to $20$ you have $20-10+1=11$ terms.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the explanation

Comment: The answer should be $\frac 1{12}n^{\color{red}{2}}(n^2-1)$.

Comment: @hypergeometric Thanks! Corrected

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's easier to swap order of summation.

First summation:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n 4=4\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}1=4\sum_{k=1}^nk=2n(n+1)\quad\blacksquare$$

Second summation:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n i^2=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i^2=
\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom i2+\binom {i+1}2=\sum_{k=n}^n\binom k3+\binom {k+1}3\\
=\binom {n+1}4+\binom {n+2}4=\frac {2n\cdot (n+1)n(n-1)}{4!}=\frac 1{12}n^2(n^2-1)\quad\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n 4 =\sum_{i=0}^n (n-i) 4 = 4n\sum_{i=0}^n 1 - 4\sum_{i=0}^ni  $$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^n i^2 = \sum_{i=0}^n (n- i)i^2 = \sum_{i=0}^n ni^2- i^3 =  n\sum_{i=0}^n i^2- \sum_{i=0}^ni^3$$